# Complex Analysis: Bounded Analytic Function & Continuously Extend

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

[image]

Not sure where to start with this question. Any information or hints would be helpful.

Comment: What is wrong  with the hint? Use a domain that has small indents at the exceptional points and the function in the hint adapted for all the points which  is analytic inside, continuous on the boundary and bounded by $M$ there since the factors are small in the indent so if $R$ is the apriori bound for $f$ multiplying with the factors take it under $M$...